# .htaccess - Strip characters '%26' from url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have been a long time reader but this is my first post. Normally I can google and problem solve my way through any issues I have, but this one has taken me many hours and I am at a loss.

On the plus side I have learnt much about the makeup of .htaccess code as opposed to all the cutting and pasting I have been doing all these years.

The issue at hand is that I am moving from an old CMS system to a new one. The old system displayed [&] ampersand characters in the url in their hex format, '%26'. The new CMS system strips this completely. I have been trying to remove this through a rewrite rule.

```
The objective is to make this url:
http://domain.com.au/drums-%26-percussion/

Redirect to this:
http://domain.com.au/drums-percussion/
```

I have tried numerous lines and combinations, but these two example are have been the closest I could get to it work.

```
Example A)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\%26(.*)$ http://domain.com.au/$1-$2 [L,NE,N,R=301]
```

This above example works if I actually use the &, not the hex format %26. For some reason unknown to me I cannot get it fire. eg, nothing happens.  I've tired so many variations around the %26.

```
Example B)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)(-%26-)(.*)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com.au/$1-$2 [L,NE,R=302]
```

I read somewhere that the %26 had to be put into a condition to be picked up. So I tried this. It reads the %26 and fires off the redirect. The issue is I am not passing on the $1 $2 values. The end result I am getting with this code is:

```
Start:
http://domain.com.au/drums-%26-percussion/
Redirect:
http://derringers.testpad.com.au/-
```

I appreciate any and all advice is this matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) states:

> On the first `RewriteRule`, it is matched against the (%-decoded) URL-path of the request.

This means that the URL you see in browser as:

```
http://domain.com.au/drums-%26-percussion/
```

is, in fact:

```
http://domain.com.au/drums-&-percussion/
```

and the `RewriteRule` tries to match `/drums-&-percussion`

Given that, the correct `RewriteRule` to match the URL is:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-&-(.*)$ http://domain.com.au/$1-$2 [L,NE,N,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on this. I had used the correct process, but for what ever reason was unable to see/test the required outcome. Sometimes you can loop around and miss the answer staring right in front of you. 

The above rewrite code works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I would like to vote this as correct but I do not have enough rep. Thanks again for your time.